# Typescript generic not constraining as expected

Tags: typescript, generics

In the following TypeScript I'm getting something unexpected:

```
class BaseNode<C> {
  id = ''
}
class ContainerClass<T> {
  nodes: Record<string, BaseNode<T>> = {};

  addNode (node: BaseNode<T>) {
    this.nodes[node.id] = node;
  }
}
class ContextOne {
  getLabel() { return 'one' }
}
class ContextTwo {
  getVal() { return 2 }
}

class GenderNode extends BaseNode<ContextOne> {}
class HeightNode extends BaseNode<ContextTwo> {}

const container = new ContainerClass<ContextOne>()
const genderNode = new GenderNode()
const heightNode = new HeightNode()
container.addNode(genderNode)
container.addNode(heightNode) // THIS WORKS, BUT SHOULD NOT
```

The `container` is of type `ContainerClass<ContextOne>`, which means it's `addNode` function should be constrained to type `addNode(node: BaseNode<ContextOne>)`. However, I'm passing in `heightNode = BaseNode<ContextTwo>`.

So the expectation was the `container.addNode()` function would only accept node instances that use the same context as the container.

Comment: TS has a *structural* type system; your `BaseNode<C>` has no dependency on `C` whatsoever, so `BaseNode<X>` and `BaseNode<Y>` are identical no matter what `X` and `Y` are.  If you add some structural dependency on `C` to `BaseNode<C>` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk861w) then things behave as expected.  Presumably there's some actual reason why you included `C` in `BaseNode<C>`, so you should express it in the type system.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, very helpful. This is a simplified example representing my real code, but adding a "structural" difference using to one of the classes seems to fix it!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  In TypeScript, types are compared by their *shape* or *structure*.  Two object types with the same members are therefore considered the same type, even if they have different names or were declared in different places.

In your example code, `BaseNode<C>` has the type `{id: string}`, which is completely structurally independent on the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `C`.  So `BaseNode<A>` and `BaseNode<B>` are both just `{id: string}`, and therefore they are identical, no matter what `A` and `B` are.  This will cause the compiler to accept all kinds of things with different names as being the same type.  See [the relevant TS FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).

If you want `GenderNode` and `HeightNode` to be considered as distinct types, then `BaseNode<C>` should depend structurally on `C`.  There are lots of ways to do this; you should do whatever best fits your use cases.  But the easiest is to add a member of type `C` to the type:

```
class BaseNode<C> {
  id = ''
  declare c: C // <-- 
}
```

Once you do that, you'll see the expected errors:

```
container.addNode(genderNode) // okay
container.addNode(heightNode) // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMByB7AJggPAYQHzQG8AoaaASzWgF5oByWk6DUMAJwWmAC5ptoB6ftEwBaEdACeKAK7QAdggSUIKALYcwwAC7SwIJggAOCORjnAJ0FHN5EAvkRZRe1rWDILW2cFEwAVfGJSOXQECB4AJQRgFFY0TAgtVg8AcwAaOERUDH9cfBoCOwBuIkYwNDRshAAKEIweeAhkUNyASkJGUi0ACzIIADo6sIBtIf6KAF1qeVCS0gcHJxhsVwQADy0AeQUO0hSELQAZMAAjBBBq9oJodh1WG1prBFpoBccfZdWNvwB3FF3oPstAA1PSXQg3A7Se7QABMr3spSW0AA4iYMKwqtB1lp0TBGs0cis5LiNtsEIEEciABIIMgpbpaLE4vGZJpVHBfLS-FCUhyOayJTiudyeaYKH4uEmihBeD6ckk48m4S4CuRC-amWVYmgS1Ho7WhVUxdVaaDdOkMpmhcUISW0+mMqrGkUeWX9cqVI2ajFVdqCKwAazAEjVbjdrA9FWdFsd1ow-qEstYsSAA)